# Why is php preforming an echo from a class function that doesn't run?

Tags: php, laravel, function, class

I have the below code being run:

```
class column_field_length_validation extends Controller
{

    private $input_column_type;
    private $input_column_field_length;
    private $input_csv_line_data;
    
    public function __construct ($recieved_input_column_type, $recieved_input_column_field_length, $received_input_csv_line_data)
    {
        $this->input_column_type = $recieved_input_column_type;
        $this->input_column_field_length = $recieved_input_column_field_length;
        $this->input_csv_line_data = $received_input_csv_line_data;
    }

    public function run ()
    {
        $type_check = $this->input_column_type;
        $csv_line_data = $this->input_csv_line_data;
        $column_field_length = $this->input_column_field_length;

        $type_check_function = [
            'string_check' => $this->string_length_check($column_field_length, $csv_line_data),
        ];

        foreach ($type_check_function as $key => $value) {
            if ($type_check == $key) {
                return $value;
            }
        }

    }

    public function string_length_check ($column_field_length, $csv_line_data)
    {
        $max_string_length = $column_field_length / 3;
        $length_check = (strlen($csv_line_data) <= $max_string_length) ? 1 : 0;
        echo 'string check preformed = ';
        return [
            'errors' => $length_check,
        ];
    }

}
```

The issue I'm having is when this class is called and $type_check doesn't equal to 'string_check' it seems the 'string_length_check' function doesn't run. However, the echo line is still being run.

The above class/code is being run via the class code below:

```
class check_csv_data_against_column_types extends Controller
{
    public function run(Request $request)
    {
        $headings_to_check = (new columns_to_be_checked)->run($request);
        $table_data = (new return_table_data)->run($request);
        $table_name = $table_data['table_name'];
        $column_types = $table_data['column_types'];
        $column_lengths = $table_data['column_lengths'];

        $csv_file = $_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'];

        $handle = fopen($csv_file, "r");
        $csv_data = fgetcsv($handle); 

        $heading_count = count($headings_to_check['headings']);

        $db = DB::table($table_name)->get();

        while (! feof($handle)) {

            $csv_line = fgetcsv($handle);

                for ($i=0; $i < $heading_count; $i++) { 

                    $current_heading = $headings_to_check['headings'][$i];
                    $current_heading_position = $headings_to_check['positions'][$i];
                    $current_column_length = $column_lengths[$i];
                    $column_type_position = $column_types[$current_heading_position];
                    $line = $csv_line[$current_heading_position] ?? 'empty line break';

                    if ($line == 'empty line break') {
                        break;
                    }

                    $type_check = (new column_type_check_required($column_type_position))->run();
                    echo $type_check;
                    echo nl2br("\r\n");
                    print_r((new csv_line_data_column_type_validation($type_check, $line))->run());
                    echo nl2br("\r\n");
                    print_r((new column_field_length_validation($type_check, $current_column_length, $line))->run());
                    echo nl2br("\r\n");
                }

        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

The result or output looks like the below:

```
int_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 1 )
EXAMPLE --> string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
string_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => for sale )
string check preformed = Array ( [errors] => 1 )
int_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
string_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => for rent )
string check preformed = Array ( [errors] => 1 )
int_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 3 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
string_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => off market )
string check preformed = Array ( [errors] => 1 )
int_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 4 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
timestamp_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => 2021-04-14 19:47:14 )
string check preformed =
string_check
Array ( [errors] => 1 [csv_line_data] => sold (subject to contract) )
string check preformed = Array ( [errors] => 1 )
```

This isn't a major issue however it would be helpfull to know if I'm doing anything wrong or how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is run, because you are calling a method as a value, so what is the value of that array index ? The resolution of the method, hence the method runs. What you have to do is a closure to prevent that.

So, this code:

```php
$type_check_function = [
    'string_check' => $this->string_length_check($column_field_length, $csv_line_data),
];
```

Should be like this:

```php
$type_check_function = [
    'string_check' => function () use ($column_field_length, $csv_line_data) {
        return $this->string_length_check($column_field_length, $csv_line_data);
    }
];
```

And then, you have to change:

```php
foreach ($type_check_function as $key => $value) {
    if ($type_check == $key) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

To:

```php
foreach ($type_check_function as $key => $value) {
    if ($type_check == $key) {
        return $value();
    }
}
```

Because `$value` is going to be:

```php
function () use ($column_field_length, $csv_line_data) {
    return $this->string_length_check($column_field_length, $csv_line_data);
}
```

So, it will execute that function, hence `$value()` and it is going to return the result of `$this->string_length_check($column_field_length, $csv_line_data)`.

Maybe we have to tweak something, but I think I did not miss anything.

Comment: Thank you - your solution has resolved the problem. I think i'll now do a bit of research on closures for future reference.

Comment: No problem ! Remember that anything you want as a value, will be resolved if it is a method, you will have to do a Closure, that is why Laravel has so many of them